# Как в цикле for модуля os языка Python пропустить пустой массив?

Tags: python, for, ос

Мне требуется обойти папку 'Voices', где вложены субдиректории `spk1`, `spk2` и так далее. В каждой из них - файлы, с которыми надо работать. Проходя функцией os.walk(), я получаю первый пустой массив:

> []
>
> ['spk_1_track_2.wav', 'spk_1_track_3.wav', 'spk_1_track_4.wav']
>
> ['spk_10_track_2.wav', 'spk_10_track_3.wav', 'spk_10_track_4.wav']
>
> ['spk_11_track_2.wav', 'spk_11_track_3.wav', 'spk_11_track_4.wav']

Для дальнейшей работы пустой список `[]` мне мешает (логика последующего кода требует там иметь файлы), посему получаю ошибку выполнения. Как можно его пропускать? (Если пишу `files[1:]`, то скрипт пропускает первый файл в каждом списке: мне этого не надо.

Код простой:

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('Voices/'):
#     print(root)
#     print(dirs)
    print(files)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавить проверку на пустой массив и теперь будет работать, как надо:

```py
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('Voices/'):
    if not files:
        continue
    print(files)
```